# How do I intercept outgoing tcp messages in node?

Tags: node.js, sockets, tcp, node-streams

How can I write a simple stream which intercepts messages?

For example, say I want to log (or eventually transform) a message being sent over the wire by a user's socket.write(...) call.

Following is a minimal program which attempts to do this:

```
const net    = require('net');
const stream = require('stream');

const socket = new net.Socket();

const transformer = new stream.Transform({
  transform(chunk,e,cb){
    console.log("OUT:"+chunk.toString());
    cb();
  }});
//const client = socket.pipe(transformer); // <= prints "OUT:" on client, but nothing on server
const client = transformer.pipe(socket); // <= prints nothing on client, but "hello world" on server

socket.on('data', (data)=>{ console.log("IN:"+data.toString()); });
socket.connect(1234, 'localhost', ()=>{ client.write("hello world"); });
```

When I do socket.pipe(transformer), the client prints "OUT:" (like I want), but doesn't actually send anything to the server. When I swap the pipe locations, transformer.pipe(socket), nothing gets printed to the client but the message gets sent to the server.

Although not listed here, I also tried to use the Writable stream, which does print the message on the client, but it is never sent to the server (if I do a this.push(...) inside the Writable stream, it still doesn't seem to send to the server)

What am I missing here?

EDIT: Reformatted the code for clarity and updated the text

Comment: reformat your code please , that one line is unreadable. So you mean something like a proxy for TCP connections?

Comment: @Mr.Phoenix , thanks, should be better formatted now. This of this as a logger. When someone calls socket.write(data), I want to print data to screen. My real problem is more complex but I need to figure out how to encapsulate processing logic in a stream which can be dropped into .pipe(...)

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding your snippet, you use transform like it's an TCP client but you only pipe it back to server and expect it the output on data event when you write data to it, cb looks incomplete, it should something like the answer below `cb(null,chunk)` , you can use `transformer.pipe(socket).pipe(client)` but it will not make any sense to whoever attempts to read this.Try reading https://github.com/substack/stream-handbook/blob/master/readme.markdown to have an better understanding of streams and maybe use dnode package which makes these kind of task less complex.

Comment: @Mr.Phoenix if you post that as an answer, I'll accept it. Looks like I needed to call .write() on transformer, not client. You message made me think of that change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like I needed to change the following line

```
socket.connect(1234, 'localhost', ()=>{ client.write("hello world"); });
```

to this

```
socket.connect(1234, 'localhost', ()=>{ transformer.write("hello world"); });
```

This is based on @Mr.Phoenix's comment. I expected .pipe() to return a new stream which I could use. I believe that is how Java's netty framework does it and I kept expecting node streams to work the same way.

Answer (score 0):

You're not writing any data out of the stream.

You need to either `this.push(chunk)` or change the call to `cb` to `cb(null, chunk)`.

[See the docs about implementing transform streams for more info.](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_implementing_a_transform_stream)

Comment: that doesn't seem to make a difference. Besides, in the example above, my data is getting to the server just fine, it just isn't being intercepted as I expected (it isn't printing "OUT:<msg>" on the client).